# Spark tasks one more than number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a simple count and group by in spark dataset.
However each time one of the stages get stuck like (200/201 1 running).
I have retried with several partitions ranging from 1000 to 6000. Each time I am stuck in a stage showing (1000/1001 1 running) or (6000/6001 1 running) in status bar.

Kindly help me as to where this extra 1 task is getting spawned from.

The spark-submit options are as below :

```
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2000m --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4000 --conf spark.default.parallelism=3000 --conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6000 --conf spark.driver.memory=30g --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 --conf spark.driver.cores=6 --num-executors 80 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 40g
```

Comment: What is your input data format?  Can you post the code so we can confirm nothing complicated or unexpected is being done?

Answer (score 0):

The number of spark shuffle partitions are huge. Spark writes the files to disk for each shuffle partition. That may take a lot of time if you have such a large number of partitions as well as shuffle partitions. You could try reducing both the default parallelism and shuffle partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without seeing your specific spark code and the input format, but the first thing I would look into is data skew in your input data.

If one task is consistently taking longer to complete it's probably because it is significantly larger than the others.  This will happen during a shuffle if one key in your data that you are grouping by shows up way more frequently than others since they will all end up in the same shuffled partition.

That being said, if you are literally just doing `df.groupBy("key").count` then Spark won't need to shuffle the values, just the intermediate sums for each key.  That's why it would be helpful to see your specific code.

Another consideration is that your input format and data will define the number of initial partitions, not your spark parallelism settings.  For example if you have 10 gzip'ed text files, you will only ever be able to have 10 input partitions.  It sounds like the stage you are seeing get stuck is changing task counts with your setting changes though, so I'm assuming it's not the first stage.

Comment: I am reading parquet files and created a view from the dataset. Later i am executing the spark sql - select key, count(key) from table group by key - and thats it.